# React native: Cookie authentication - Web View

Tags: react-native, cookies, axios, keycloak, react-native-web

I have a react native app in which I use Web view for authentication from Keycloak and after successful authentication it sets some cookies and I redirect to the react native app screens, then one of the screen make a call to the back end to pull data using axios networking library, In that request cookies were not sent to the back end even I specify withCredentials: true in the request header, the server rejects that api call, Why the web view cookies were not included in the axios request. It is working with localhost server, but not testing servers

Answer (score 0):

On cookies. Make sure about the cookie's "SameSite" setting.

See below explenation from https://andrewlock.net/understanding-samesite-cookies/:

“Lax Means that the cookie is not sent on cross-site requests, such as on requests to load images or frames, but is sent when a user is navigating to the origin site from an external site (for example, when following a link).”

“None Means that the browser sends the cookie with both cross-site and same-site requests. The Secure attribute must also be set when setting this value, like so SameSite=None; Secure. If Secure is missing an error will be logged”

If your website is using cookies and is on "some@domain.com" and your server is on "another@domain". It won't send the cookie through if it is "SameSite=Lax". When you test it locally both the server and your client is on the same "domain" ( localhost ).

Hope this helps.